Random navigations occurs in Expo router while interacting with a Native UI component (Android)
I am working on a react-native SDK that provides react native UI Components. Basic views that display scrollable lists of images.
In order to test them, I created an Expo project. I used create-expo-app with the template Navigation (Typescript). I then added a few routes and in each one of them, I implemented my Native UI Components.
Everything seems to work, my components load and work fine but sometimes, when I interact with them, a random navigation occurs. It can happen at any time (as far as I can tell). It only happens on Android build, not on iOS.
I tried simplifying my components to see if it was a specific native API. But it seems to occur wit h a simple FrameLayout. I still have a random navigation to one of the app's routes.
I have no clues why it behaves like this. As far as I can tell, it is linked to Expo itself and the way it handles native UI Components.

I was able to find the root of the problem. My recycler View instanciate a bunch of native views with random Ids. But since these views are not handled by React native itself, they end up with the same ids as other views. So when user clicks, React native is confused and triggers events on the wrong views. I still don't know how to make React native aware of these subviews.
